# Filtering an array of arrays that contain a dictionary using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array titled charactersAndDescriptions that contains several arrays, and in each of those arrays is an NSDictionary with two keys/values. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to filter this array on the value for the key 'desc,' comparing it against a string variable searchText (and it should return results where that string exists anywhere in the desc). I want the returned structure to be the same as the original - arrays containing a dictionary inside an array. Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"desc contains[c] %@", searchText];
self.resultsArray = [self.charactersAndDescriptions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

The problem is, self.resultsArray always returns 0 objects. I don't see why that's the case. I was looking at questions on here where they had only one array of dictionaries but couldn't find any for nested arrays. Hoping you can help, thanks!

Comment: You have to do a deep search since it is a multi level array

Comment: I want the returned structure to be the same as the original - still arrays of a dictionary in an array. How do I do a deep search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it with a single predicate. But you can iterate through individual array of dictionaries, filter them and add the filtered list to your final array. Try something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"desc contains[c] %@", searchText];
NSMutableArray *finalColletion = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *temp in self.charactersAndDescriptions) {
    NSArray *result =[temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if([result count] > 0) {
        [finalColletion addObject:result];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but the check for `[result count] > 0` will prevent your code from generating an output array that matches the input array.  The check is not needed since `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` will return a valid empty array when there are no matches.

Comment: 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate' will return an empty array if there are no matches.. there is no need to add it to the final resultant array. Hence the check.. Why will it precent from generating the output array? It will generate  valid output array

Comment: The top-level array indexes won't match unless the result array includes the empty arrays, but that may or may not matter depending on how he's using the result array.

Comment: It does indeed matter, really only to simplify the code a bit when filling in the data source methods, so I did remove that if statement. Huge thanks to both of you! That was the last piece to the puzzle and now my search is working perfect and I may get some much needed rest tonight. :)